# Total Variation Between Finite Measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, total-variation

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n\in \mathbb{R}^k$ be distinct and $0\leq a_i,b_i\leq 1$ be such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1 = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i$.  Define the finite measures $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta_{x_i}$ and $\nu=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i y_i$.  What is the *total variation measure*
$|\mu-\nu|$ explicitly?

The underlying measurable space is $(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k))$ where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^k$.

I expect that it should be something like
$$
|\mu|(A) := \sup_{i,j:(x_i,y_i)\in A^2} \sum_{i,j\leq N}|a_i-b_j| \delta_{(x_i,y_j)}
$$

Comment: What is the underlying measurable space?

Comment: I added the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X:=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{x_i\}$ and $Y:=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{y_i\}$. By definition, for $E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$,
$$
|\mu-\nu|(E)=\sup\{|(\mu-\nu)(A)|+|(\mu-\nu)(B)|:A,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k),A\cap B=\emptyset,A\cup B\subseteq E\}.
$$
Since $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, we have,
$$
|\mu-\nu|(E)\ge \mu(E\cap X)+\nu(E\cap Y).
$$
On the other hand, for any $A,B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ s.t. $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B\subseteq E$,
\begin{align}
|(\mu-\nu)(A)|+|(\mu-\nu)(B)|&\le \mu(A)+\nu(A)+\mu(B)+\nu(B) \\
&=\mu(A\cup B)+\nu(A\cup B) \\
&\le \mu(E\cap X)+\nu(E\cap Y).
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
|\mu-\nu|(E)=\mu(E\cap X)+\nu(E\cap Y).
$$

Comment: So then, for any $z \in \mathbb{R}^k$ we have: $|\mu-\nu|(z) = \sum_{i} a_i I(z=x_i) + \sum_j b_j (z=y_j)$?  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the question and thought we were talking about the TV distance, not the TV measure.  Leaving this answer for "historical purposes".

If all the "base points" are distinct, the total variation between these measures is 1.

Take, for instance, $A = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ (the support of $\mu$).  Then $\mu(A) = 1$ but $\nu(A) = 0$, so $\vert \mu(A)-\nu(A)\vert = 1$; this is the largest possible value of $\vert \mu(A)-\nu(A)\vert$, since any other set might include a support point of $\nu$, hence $\nu(A)>0$ and so $\mu(A)-\nu(A)\leq 1$.

If the base points are allowed to be shared between the measures, things are a little more interesting, but I'll let you work out the details.

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed... you say the total variation between these is "1" but $|\mu-\nu|$ is a measure and not a number...

Comment: How do you define "total variation measure"? I'm not familiar with this notion.  The total variation *distance* is a metric on probability measures, so it returns a number $\vert\mu-\nu\vert_{TV} = \sup_{A\in\mathcal{F}}\vert\mu(A)-\nu(A)\vert$.

Comment: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Signed_measure#Total_variation

Comment: OK, sorry, I didn't read the original question carefully enough. You should include the definition in your question, but I'll probably delete my answer since it doesn't apply.

Comment: That's alright... I still appreciate it it helps with the ideas